# Troubleshooting RDP Connection

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, remote-access

This is an issue in my office .I am able to take RDP for apponfly VM instance but not for Google and AWS .
This there anything from which I can Test the connection or difference in RDP file from them.
Thanks in advance

Comment: From where are you trying to RDP? What RDP client are you using?   Are you receiving any Error messages?  Did you make sure that you have opened the appropriate port to make connection (in this case, TCP port 3389 for RDP ) in the GCE firewall so that traffic can reach the instance and check your own network firewall was blocking outbound RDP?

Comment: As @KarthickN has said, you need to provide more information.

Comment: @KarthickN I am using Windows Remote Desktop as my client , secondly I have double checked TCP port 3389 is open ,I am able to take RDP for VM provided by &#39;apponfly&#39; , but not google cloud VM , Error I am Getting is &quot;Remote Server is not Available&quot; , but as I said I am able to take RDP using Microsoft&#39;s app in my Phone ,I want to take RDP of Google Cloud VM from the same system where I am taking apponfly RDP ,Hope I was able to explain you the scenario

Comment: @nbryans please refer to reply of karthikN ,
Thanks in advance

Comment: The error indicates there is no connection between the user's client and the server. With the port for RDP being opened in the GCP firewall, I highly suspect the issue with network firewall or your own system. Also, If you don't have a preference, I would advice you to install the [Chrome RDP](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-rdp-for-google-clo/mpbbnannobiobpnfblimoapbephgifkm/) for Google Compute Engine Icon for RDP extension extension, and try to connect to the external IP (static or ephemeral) and see if that works.

Comment: @karthickN
I tried using Chrome RDP also , I think problem is with my own system